Pyhton script to check for daily text changes to the copy of multiple web pages (60+ pages)
I need to keep track of terms and conditions pages and monitor for changes. Here is one of the pages I want to monitor, its from Meta Advertising Standards. When a change is detected I am totally happy to manually check the page to see how the terms and conditions have changed. In total there are 60+ pages to monitor, one for each placement type.
This script to check these would not be run on a server but will be run daily on my laptop which is turned off at night.
I found this solution on geeksforgeeks.org
# Importing libraries 
import time 
import hashlib 
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request 
  
# setting the URL you want to monitor 
url = Request('www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/update/image/facebook-feed', 
              headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
# to perform a GET request and load the 
# content of the website and store it in a var 
response = urlopen(url).read() 
  
# to create the initial hash 
currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest() 
print("running") 
time.sleep(10) 
while True: 
    try: 
        # perform the get request and store it in a var 
        response = urlopen(url).read() 
  
        # create a hash 
        currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest() 
  
        # wait for 30 seconds 
        time.sleep(30) 
  
        # perform the get request 
        response = urlopen(url).read() 
  
        # create a new hash 
        newHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest() 
  
        # check if new hash is same as the previous hash 
        if newHash == currentHash: 
            continue
  
        # if something changed in the hashes 
        else: 
            # notify 
            print("something changed") 
  
            # again read the website 
            response = urlopen(url).read() 
  
            # create a hash 
            currentHash = hashlib.sha224(response).hexdigest() 
  
            # wait for 30 seconds 
            time.sleep(30) 
            continue
  
    # To handle exceptions 
    except Exception as e: 
        print("error") 

This is for continual checking and it only handles one website. I'm not sure if this is the best choice but after the browsing for solutions it seemed the simplest one that should work for my use case.
If this is the right way to go, I would like to modify this script to:

Check multiple sites in the same script
Compare against a daily benchmark which implies to me it will need to store the results from the previous day and check it against the new results.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, I am a newbie to this so learning as I go - so if you could use the simplest explanations when giving suggestions or things to look at it would be much appreciated. Also open to other suggestions that may provide a better alternative.
I used the above geeksforgeeks script and substitued the URL for the Facebook one and its returning me an unknown URL type. However, this doesn't cover comparing a saved result and checking multiple URLS in one script.

You have not posted any code so I am having to make a guess her. But the obvious solution is to create a function that accepts a URL and finds the details that you are checking against. You then call that function as many times as you need passing in each web address.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

That solution will check if anything about the page changes (including things you can't see) – if you want something to check text changes only, that'd need some more code (e.g. the html2text module).

Thanks for your comments, I will check out the html2text module

If you discover that the digest (hash value) has changed, why are you re-fetching the same URL and re-computing the hash again? Also, after if newHash == currentHash: continue, you do not need an else clause since the continue causes control to return to the top of the while True: loop. You should look into multithreading with either the multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool class or the concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor class or using asyncio. Update your post with your best effort to process multiple pages concurrently.

After reading the comments here and doing some research it seems the easiest way may be:

Use beauiful soup to extract the  information - looking at the websites I want to monitor this is exactly where the info I want is.
Store the extraction as a CSV.
Compare the extraction with the last CSV entry
If different send alert and copy of last entry and new extraction to me
If different save the new extraction in the CSV

As I am pretty much a beginner I guess I can solve each of those problems sequentially until I have my final script ... and I have 64 webpages to do it for!

Thanks for your comments @Booboo I had taken a found script and was trying to modify it some degree (it was doing all the stuff you highlighted as that was what was included). Although it will take longer its probably better for me to start from scratch and build up to the final result I want
